# Show numbers in horizontal recyclerview with max 5 rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Show dynamic list of numbers in **horizontal scrolled recyclerview** with max 5 rows. Numbers size depend on current weeks number. If current weeks number is 45, then there will be 45 items. I can show them as below (vertically increasing) with `GridLayoutManager`.

```
1   6  11  16 
2   7  12  17
3   8  13  18
4   9  14  19
5  10  15  20

<----------->
```

But I want them to be shown as below (horizontal increasing)

```
1   2   3   4   5

6   7   8   9  10

11 12  13  14  15

16 17  18  19  20

21 22  23  24  24

<--------------->
```

Here just for simplicity I started numbers from 1. In real application numbers can start from 100 or 1000.

**Edit**

Now what I've.

[image]

As you can see numbers are decreased vertically. I want them to be decreased horizontally.

Below is my adapter

```
class SINumberAdapter(val context: Context, val list:List<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<SINumberAdapter.NumberViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NumberViewHolder {

        val textView = TextView(parent.context)
        textView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val paddingInPixels = 5.toPx
        textView.setPadding(paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels)
        return NumberViewHolder(textView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NumberViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.text = list[position]
    }

    inner class NumberViewHolder(val view:TextView):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `RecyclerView` grid layout for this purpose

Comment: create an item for your recyclerview with 5 textviews and inflate them in horizontal orientation

Comment: @VivekMishra How? Columns size can be from 1 to 11, rows maximum 5.

Comment: that's what I meant to say make your one row as one item of your recyclerview.

Comment: @VivekMishra I already did so. But how to show them horizontally increasing or decreasing way.

Comment: can you show the code for the same

Comment: Is this the default behaviour ? If you are using GridLayoutManager + RecyclerView ?

Comment: I'm using `GridLayoutManager` + `RecyclerView`

Comment: Your list is sorted ?

Comment: @RohitSingh Image is cropped from real application. In real application I reverse number list to show in decreased order. In question just for simplicity I asked to show in increasing order.

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer

Assuming that max column size is fixed or will be known before setting the adapter.

following global declarations

```
int maxColumn = 8;
int spanCount = 1;
String list[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
        "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"};
```

inside onCreate

```
spanCount = list.length / maxColumn + 1;

mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, spanCount, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

above I calculated the required span size for a given length of array and number of column

sample adapter code

```
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    int firstRowPos = 0;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_item, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

        int adapterColumn = position / spanCount;
        int adapterRow = position - adapterColumn * spanCount;

        int calcPos = maxColumn * adapterRow + adapterColumn;

        if (calcPos < list.length)
            holder.txtView.setText(list[calcPos]);
        else
            holder.txtView.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return spanCount * maxColumn;
    }
}
```

in adapter total count is returned as product of number of columns and number of rows (calculated span size)

now assume a grid of size column x row
write down the position of the elements in each cell as you want (going horizontally in your case), for example below

```
req
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12 13
14 15
```

but the arrangement in recycler view will be as

```
curr
0  3  6  9  12  15
1  4  7  10 13
2  5  8  11 14
```

from here you just need to figure out the formula which will be a function of position, row number, column number

Care has to be taken though for the places where the above formula gives values more than array length

Output screen shot
[image: output image]

Comment: How to show this  [
    "792",
    "793",
    "794",
    "795",
    "796",
    "797",
    "798",
    "799",
    "800",
    "801",
    "802",
    "803",
    "804",
    "805",
    "806",
    "807",
    "808",
    "809",
    "810",
    "811",
    "812",
    "813",
    "814",
    "815",
    "816",
    "817",
    "818",
    "819",
    "820",
    "821",
    "822",
    "823",
    "824",
    "825",
    "826",
    "827",
    "828",
    "829",
    "830",
    "831",
    "832",
    "833",
    "834",
    "835",
    "836"
]

Comment: As I said items must be horizontally scrolled not vertically.